# In an Android ConstraintLayout, what is the tools:layout_constraintTop_creator attribute for?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In this code snippet, what does it mean to have the `tools:layout_constraintTop_creator` attribute set to "1"?

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/passenger_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewPassengerLabel"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
    android:letterSpacing="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the namespace implies (tools:layout_constraintTop_creator), it's purely used by Android Studio -- those attributes (using the namespace tool) are actually stripped out when the xml file is pushed on a device.

So it shouldn't be used :)

Now if you want to know how Studio use those, it's actually simple: we use the creator attributes to keep track of who created the constraints, particularly if they are created by the inference engine, as we want to scrap them / replace them in some cases.